# Setting a virtual attribute in a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, virtual-attribute

I am trying to find a way of setting a virtual attribute in a scope.  The background is I have *customers* who belong to *accounts*.  Customers can purchase *salesitems*.  I have a table customers_salesitem that shows which customers have bought what items in the past.

I would like to generate a list of salesitems with an additional field 'category' that categorises the salesitems into those that have been bought by the customer, those that have been bought by a different customer from the same account, and those that have not been bought by anyone on the account.  Ultimately, I want to use the scope for an autocomplete field but that is a little off at the moment.

I have tried a few things along the lines of:

```
class Salesitem < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :customers_salesitems

    scope :previous_customer_purchase, lambda {
        |customer|
        select("*").
        select("'Previous Customer Purchase' as category").
        where ("salesitems.id IN (SELECT customers_salesitems.salesitem_id FROM customers_salesitems WHERE customer_id = ?)",
            customer.id)          
    }

    def category
        @category
    end

    def category=(value)
        @category = @attributes["category"] = value
    end
end
```

Although the SQL is correctly generated the scope returns an item list without category.

Answer (score 0):

Although the where method and some other of the new Rails 3 query methods can be chained with an accumulated affect, some do not merge.  I don't think the select method merges.  Unfortunately, much of this new functionality is not well documented.  The documentation for select is

```
select(value = Proc.new)
```

I think what you will need is:

```
scope :previous_customer_purchase, lambda {
    |customer|
    select("*, 'Previous Customer Purchase' as category").
    where ("salesitems.id IN (SELECT customers_salesitems.salesitem_id FROM customers_salesitems WHERE customer_id = ?)",
        customer.id)          
}
```